# simplification of maximization of quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, optimization, random-matrices

I am analyzing the the following problem:

\begin{equation}
\max \limits_{x \in D} x^t A x 
\end{equation}

where $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a set and $A$ is random matrix with all independent entries of the following form. $(A_{ii})_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ are all iid Gaussian random variables with mean zero and variance two and $(A_{ij})_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}$ are all iid Gaussian random variables with mean zero and variance one. The rest of the entries are defined trough the symmetry constraint $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$ for $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$.

Now we know that ([see this lecture](https://mycourses.aalto.fi/pluginfile.php/455485/mod_resource/content/1/lecture1.pdf) Lemma 2) the distribution of $A$ is invariant under orthogonal conjugation. Since $A$ is symmetric we can hence assume that $A$ has the same distribution as the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ having the eigenvalues $\lambda_1(A), \ldots \lambda_n(A)$ of $A$ as diagonal entries (just compute some eigendecomposition of $A$).

**Question**: Is then also the above maximization problem equivalent to

\begin{equation}
\max \limits_{x \in D} x^t \Lambda x \quad ?
\end{equation}

This would simplify the original problem a lot since the quadratic form is a function of the eigenvalues only. If it is not equivalent could you shortly argue why that is. This might be a trivial question but I am new to this topic. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  $A = U^t\Lambda U$ for orthogonal matrix $U$, then $x^t A x = (U x)^t \Lambda (U x)$.
So maximizing $x^t A x$ for $x \in D$ is equivalent to maximizing $y^t \Lambda y$ for $y \in U(D)$.  If $D$ happens to be invariant under orthogonal transformations (e.g. the unit ball),
your two problems are the same.  Otherwise they are not.

EDIT: Here's an amusing example.  Take $n=2$ and $D = \{e_1, e_2, v\}$  where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the standard unit vectors and $v = (e_1+e_2)/\sqrt{2}$.  If $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix, $v^t \Lambda v = \frac{1}{2} e_1^t \Lambda e_1 + \frac{1}{2} e_2^t \Lambda e_2$, so $\max_{x \in D} x^t \Lambda x = \max_{x \in \{e_1, e_2\}} x^t \Lambda x$.  On the other hand, if $A_{12}$ is large enough compared to $A_{11}$ and $A_{22}$, 
$v^t A v > \max(e_1^t A e_1, e_2^t A e_2)$.  Thus $\max_{x\in D} x^t A x$ and 
$\max_{x \in \{e_1, e_2\}} x^t A x$ have different distributions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your argument is true in general. What about the case (random) I described? Can we at least say that in expectation the the two maximum values coincide? I'm still a little confused because the matrices are the same in distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by "the matrices are the same in distribution"?  The distribution of eigenvalues is the same.  The distribution of the matrices themselves is not: $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix, $A$ is almost surely not.

Comment: I think your misunderstanding comes from this: for any **fixed** orthogonal matrix $U$, $A$ and $U A U^t$ have the same distribution.  But to diagonalize $A$ requires an orthogonal matrix that is **not** fixed: it depends on $A$.

Comment: Now its clear. Very useful explanation.